spring falla la prueba de context loads con error java.lang.IllegalStateException
tengo un problema, al construir mi proyecto en spring con gradle me sale error en la clase test, pero si ejecuto el proyecto me funciona sin problemas
Task :test FAILED

InventarioApplicationTests > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at Assert.java:76

1 test completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.



Si ese es el único test que tienes en tu proyecto yo casi que lo borraba y me evitaba el problema, aunque es posible que esté fallando el test por algún problema real con tu proyecto, el test por defecto de spring simplemente verifica que el proyecto pueda iniciarse, pero como afirmas que funciona... no te sirve de mucho el test. Si realmente te interesa corregirlo, empieza por poner el código como texto y no pegar imágenes del mismo. Asumo que tu clase principal (donde tienes el main) está marcada con @SpringBootApplication, correcto?

si claro, es que en general todo esta bien, y al ejecutarlo funciona, falla en la construccion solamente

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Cargar imágen con maven da NPE ( Couldn't find file )

ya lo pude solucionar, resulta que la estructura de carpetas tanto para el "main" y el "test" deben de ser iguales
